# Reading an Excel (xlsx) file in C# adds extra characters to columns containing Kanji

Tags: c#, .net, stream, xlsx

I have stumbled on a curious issue in C#.    I am importing a xlsx file into a C# program to import users via bulk invite.   The majority of the spreadsheet is in Kanji, however there is one column with English (western) values.

When looping through the rows, the Kanji values get extra characters appended to them, but the English values come through ok.

The excel file has three columns:

- 名
- 姓
- メールアドレス

**The spreadsheet has two rows, here is a sample:**

`一二三     小鳥遊    xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com`

When I loop through the spreadsheet in the debugger, here is what it comes through as

`一二三イチニサン   小鳥遊コトリアソ  xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com`

Note the extra characters.   At first I thought they were the column headers, but they don't match.   I don't read Kanji, so apologies if I am missing something obvious.

**C#**

```
public static DataSet GetDataSetFromExcelStream(Stream excel, string fileName, bool FirstRowAsColumns)
{
    DataSet worksheets = new DataSet();
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).Replace(".", "");
    IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;
    ExcelFormat ext = ExcelFormat.xls;
    if (Enum.TryParse<ExcelFormat>(extension, out ext))
    {
        switch (ext)
        {
            case ExcelFormat.xls:
                excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(excel);
                break;
            case ExcelFormat.xlsx:
                excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(excel);
                break;
        }
        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = FirstRowAsColumns;
        worksheets = excelReader.AsDataSet();
    }
    return worksheets;
}
```

Comment: **Not** an answer: try using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) so you can at least see what data you're dealing with. When I tried, the data parsed is different (not really "extra").  So is it possible you're just _viewing_ wrapped or truncated data in Excel?

Comment: The issue has to do with reading unicode characters.  The XmlReader defaults to utf-8 and the binary reader reads character one byte at a time (instead unicode is one and two bytes).  Use filestream option and set filestream to unicode encoding.  See : https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/11070923/

Comment: @jdweng if you put this in as an answer i'll accept it.